# GPU Rendering Slower?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

After looking around the web for a while, I've gathered that GPU rendering in Blender is supposed to be much faster than CPU rendering, but on my machine, the CPU is actually slightly faster? My GPU is a GTX 1070ti with a 200mhz OC and my CPU is an i5-8400. Rendering a simple image takes around 45 seconds on the CPU and 50 seconds on the GPU even with the 200mhz OC. Is there something I messed up in the settings? Or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: What tile size are you using when rendering on GPU? Usually for GPU you want to use large tiles ( like 28X128 or 256X256) whereas with GPU you want to use small tiles (16x16 or 32x32)

Comment: "*I've gathered that GPU rendering in Blender is supposed to be much faster than CPU rendering*" That will largely depend on what CPU and what GPU you use and many other unforeseen performance factors

Comment: In case your tile-size is wrong, there is a usefull Add-on called "Auto Tile Size", which sets the best tile-size for your hardware. Works quite well and is easy to use.

Answer (score -5):

use the CPU
she will be faster,
leave the video card just for video,
blender works best with CPU

Comment: Could you provide any references for your statement? There are multiple scenarios where people use GPU to render just fine, like e.g. some [Blender 2.79 benchmarks](https://blenderartists.org/t/the-new-cycles-gpu-2-79-benchmark/697314/4) and 1070 is far from simple card to not have CUDA support (so it actually has and works).